# In which language Boxee.tv IPTV software developed in?

Tags: python, flash, air, boxee

I want to know the programming language used by Boxee.tv guys to build their IPTV software. My company is building a IPTV software which will fetch channels and stream channels from the internet.

Boxee's desktop client does the same. Since we want to create a Similar UI, I would like to know what have they used to create such a UI.

Is it flash or AIR , I see some python DLLs when I inspected their folder inside program files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Boxee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxee) is a fork of the famous free and open source media player [XBMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbmc).
C++ is the main language (Python language is used mainly for plugins)